# Rails: Bundle Install fails to install necessary gem after downloading from github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, bundle

I have cloned from my github account a repo, I am getting the following error, when i run bundle install. i cant understand the reason for it. **The repo had been pushed from my pc and now i am cloning it to my laptop**

```
An error occurred while installing sassc (2.2.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sassc -v '2.2.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  sass-rails was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on
    sassc-rails was resolved to 2.1.2, which depends on
      sassc
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a known issue:
https://github.com/sass/sassc-ruby/issues/153

Solution:

1. add `gem 'sassc', '~> 2.1.0'` to your gemfile.
2. run `bundle install`

This will force it to use sassc version 2.1.0 which doesn't have the compile issue with Rails 6.

---

As a tip, whenever a gem fails to install or conflicts with another gem, it's a good idea to go check out the gem itself. 99% of the time, the code is on GitHub.

If you're new to this, try following these steps:

1. Gems in your gemfile come from https://rubygems.org by default, so visit that site and search for the gem exactly as it's named in your gemfile. In this case, it's here: https://rubygems.org/gems/sassc
2. On the gem's info page, find links on the righthand side. Click 'homepage'. For sassc, it takes you to this URL: https://github.com/sass/sassc-ruby
3. Click on the issues tab and look for anything related to the thing you're struggling with. In this case, I found about 3. Read through those issues and see if people have posted solutions or work-arounds.

Happy gem hunting!